# Balls on Hills - Loop Deduction Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This puzzle is a loop deduction puzzle, like Slitherlink and Masyu.  It is based on the idea of balls rolling down hills - the clues here give the distance that a ball can roll down.

### **The Puzzle**

[image: The puzzle grid]

**Standard Loop Deduction Rules**

1. There is a single, closed, non-intersecting loop.
2. There is a unique solution.

**Clue Rules**

1. There is a ball at every number.  The value of the number indicates the deepest depth the ball could roll down to.  It must roll down to this depth along at least one path, but it does not have to roll down to this depth along every path.
2. Arrows indicate direction of gravity for the ball.
3. Grid boundary stops the ball as if it were part of the loop, regardless of whether there is a loop segment at the boundary.

**Mechanics of Rolling Balls**

1. A ball can roll down any corner.
2. A ball cannot roll "up" (against gravity) a wall or along two "horizontal" (perpendicular to gravity) segments in a row (the hill would be too shallow!).

Here are a few examples of the ball rolling mechanic:

[image: Examples of balls]

The example in red is an impossible situation - the number indicates the deepest a ball could roll, but that ball could roll a depth of two if it went right.  The other examples have the path of the deepest roll traced out in green.

[image: Even more examples]

Note that balls can overlap.

### **Extra**

It should be solvable using logical deductions rather than guessing - you may need to prove by contradiction, but you shouldn't need to think far ahead to do so.  You shouldn't have to use the uniqueness condition in your deduction.

I found this fairly difficult to solve, even though I had the advantage of knowing what the solution would be.  A decent part of the difficulty, in my opinion, comes from the fact that it's hard to reason about the boundary of the grid, since clues don't directly inform you about whether there is an edge there.  Often in loop deduction puzzles, it's easiest to start from the edge and work your way inwards.

Hope you enjoy it! Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Nice puzzle! And welcome to Puzzling! I wonder if someone can make a Penpa link for this

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure how to make the arrows nice in Penpa, so it's quite ugly, but [here you go](https://tinyurl.com/2p2mcp7p) :)

(Edit: There was a mistake in first link, forgot an arrow)

Comment: There can be an edge that is on the grid boundary, right? Like the left edge in your top left example?

Comment: Is it allowed for balls to overlap? In other words, can a ball be in the same final resting position as another ball, or do the balls stack on each other?

Comment: Yes, edges on the boundary are allowed

Comment: Yep, overlapping is alright as well :)  They do not stack

Comment: Can you explain this one: "The value of the number indicates the deepest depth the ball could roll down to". So it can stop before the deepest depth?

Comment: At least one path it could roll down must be exactly that depth, but there may be other paths it could roll down that are shallower (but **not** deeper).  I'll edit the post to make it more clear, thanks for pointing it out!


In the examples, the top left one (the one with the two) has two paths it could roll down, one of which has depth exactly 2 and the other which has depth less than 2 - hence the example is valid.

Comment: Sure - I'll edit the post shortly with an arrowed example pic.  If the ball can fall along gravity, it must fall along gravity.  So if there was no edge blocking the sideways ball, it would have to fall sideways.  But if there was an edge, then it might roll directly down at most one cell.  It's a bit hard to put in words so I'll try to add an example that clarifies this.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, I think the phrase "balls on hills" doesn't really quite match the mechanism itself. It gives the imagery that each cell has a height, and that the balls need to find a path rolling down (where down is the direction that goes into the screen from your eyes). Probably this mechanism is better visualized as pachinko machine or pinball, where down is where the gravity arrows point to, and the loops form like pockets/barriers for the balls to fall into. This is how I visualized it in my head while solving it.

Comment: That's fair - I like the comment about pockets b/c I think it fits nicely with how some of the last few steps are reasoned about in this puzzle, and I can imagine a part of the strategy in larger puzzles is in creating large enough pockets near the grid boundary to partition the direction the balls have to fall.  So maybe a name involving the word pocket might be best?  I'll have a think on it, and am open to suggestions!

Comment: Are you saying that the balls will roll there and you have to build a wall around them, or that you have to build a wall to prevent the balls from rolling any further?

Comment: A ball with the number n will always roll down exactly n squares along one of its trajectories, and no further (so something will have to stop it from rolling down further).  (Thus you know that you'll have to build a wall somewhere n squares away to stop them from rolling further.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

Explanation:

> First, we know that in the direction of 0 is going there should be an edge. Also a number can't go directly to another number that goes in the same direction that is not exactly one less. So 1->1-> needs to be separated by edge, as well as two occurrences of 4->2->
>  [image]

Next,

> We focus on lower right 3 going left. The two next possible edges should not be edges (I put X in the spots). If any of those were an edge, the 3 will join the 4 at the bottom of it.
>  [image]
>  (If there were an edge at R5 C3-4 we will get this to prevent 3 to join the 4, and the 1 Down at R6C3 and the 4 Left at R6C5 clash. Either of them will be blocked, since we will need to continue the loop there.)
>  [image]

Next,

> The 1 at R5C2 must go to the right to reach depth 1, since it can't go to the left since it will join the 2. So R5C4-R6C4 must be blank too. And to continue the loop, it must go around the 0 and to the right.
>  [image]

Next,

> Column 2, R5-R6 if it's an edge, then the edge will continue to the left and down to allow for the 2 Down to reach depth of 2. But this edge will necessarily block the 4 Left at R6C5. So the edge to the left of R5C3 must be present, to prevent 1 to go to the left and joining the 2.
>  Similarly, bottom of R3C4 must be an edge since there is no way to reach depth 4 if going down there.
>  [image]

Next,

> Then continue the loop on the right. This is the only way to not block the 3 Down and 1 Right, while avoiding creating a loop around the 2 in the center.
>  [image]

Next,

> Now R4 C1-2 must be edge, to confirm the depth 2 and 3 going left.
>  Also the edge below 5 Down should be there, since otherwise it will be stuck inside at depth 4.
>  [image]

Finally,

> To close the loop there is really only one way. The other way will block either the 5 Down or 4 Right.
>  [image]

Comment: Awesome job!  Your second step was nice; I didn't realize that so my solution was more drawn out.  Congrats :)

Comment: @BaileyA I missed one case in that part, but I just fixed it, the core concept is the same. Thanks for creating this cool puzzle! You made this mechanics yourself?

Comment: Yes - I love puzzles like Slitherlink/Masyu/Corral so I wanted to try my hand at making up some loop deduction mechanics myself.  I didn't check if anyone has made a similar puzzle type before, though.  I'm glad you liked it :)

Comment: " a number can't go directly to another number that goes in the same direction that is not exactly one less." I don't follow. How do you know that?

Comment: "So 1->1-> needs to be separated by edge, as well as two occurrences of 4->2->"
I don't follow. Why can't they both just move 1 space?

Comment: @Bwhite There are four different directions of gravity. 1->1-> both point right, so gravity makes the ball fall to the right when it starts from these two cells. The numbers indicate the distance they need to fall to the right before coming to a rest, not including the distance up or down.

The right-hand '1' has a gravity well one cell to the right. Without knowing more, this might be top right, immediate right, or bottom right. The left hand '1' also has a gravity well to its top right or bottom right but it must not enter the first gravity well because then it would fall 2 units.

Comment: @BWhite it's because the balls need to stop exactly at that distance, and since two balls starting at the same cell with the same direction will follow the same path, they can't have two different distances.